# node.js Express with HTTP-AUTH

Tags: node.js, express, http-authentication, digest-authentication, http-auth

I have problem with creating node.js application based on express with [http-auth](http://http-auth.info) module.

It's a possible create Middleware for this **http-auth** library I have this code:

```
    //Configure Middlewares
logger.configure(function() {

  //All output has content type json
  logger.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.contentType('application/json');
    next();
  });

  //Create digest auth middleware
  logger.use(function(req, res, next){
    digest.apply();
    next();
  });
});
```

After applying this, when I connect to site I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

Is there any solution for this problem or use another method?

I need digest auth for the whole application.

Comment: logger is instance of express application.

Comment: Just use proper pattern for `http-auth` integration with `connect`.

Answer (score 1):

I think apply() is expecting the request object (hence it can't read the headers);

try this syntax:

```
digest.apply(req, res, function(username) {

});
```

Comment: This might work but when i want go to any route like, i have empty response.

Comment: The apply function is asynchronous, so you'll probably have to call next() in the apply callback.  Of course what you describe could be something unrelated.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore for `http-auth` module.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use it with [correct pattern](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth):

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var digest = auth.digest({
  realm: "Simon Area.",
  file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htdigest"
});

// Configure Middlewares
logger.configure(function() {
  // Create digest auth middleware
  logger.use(auth.connect(digest));

  // All output has content type json.
  logger.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.contentType('application/json');
    next();
  });    
});
```